# HTML dock to bottom

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, dock

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="gallery-item">
  <a href="ddd.pdf" style="display:block; width: 100%;">
    <span id="filename_1" style="white-space: nowrap;">Hello</span>
  </a>
  <div id="commands">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="https://blob">
    <a href="sdfasdfasdfasdf">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery-item {
  border: 1px #AAA solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding 2px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}    
  .gallery-item #commands {
    line-height: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    bottom: 1px;
  }
```

I want to align `commands` div to the bottom of `gallery-item` classed div. None of the above worked, the `commands` sticks to the preceding element:

[image]

Comment: Nops, coincidentally the file name is trimmed as you can see in the bottom-right tile, it's originally "analysis". Anyway I do hope the secretary I'm working with will give it a thought.

Comment: BTW, [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19913/javascript-function-optimization/19915#19915)'s the trimming function. You're welcomed to comment on!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the parent.

```css
.gallery-item {
    position: relative;
}

.gallery-item #commands {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
}
```

When you are using `position`ing, you need to specify explicitly.