# Any way to anchor a footer section in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I created a wrapper for my app in React. I am trying to get the footer to stay at the absolute bottom of the page but when the children render, the footer stays at the original bottom of the page and does not resize with the page. Code below. (imagine a scrollable page with a footer in the middle now after child renders).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from "./Header"; 
import Footer from "./Footer";

export default class Wrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="app-wrapper">
            <Header/>
                <div className="content">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            <div>
              <Footer/>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not that good at CSS. Any ideas as to what I could try? I have already tried googling around for solutions to no avail.I have tried the basic solutions such as position:relative; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; position: fixed, position: absolute etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give `position: relative|fixed` (depending on your needs) to the parent container.
For exemple :

```
<div style={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: '0' }}>
  <Footer />
</div>
```

[HTML dock to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027257/html-dock-to-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the confusion guys. I had the style redefined in my css file so my styles were being overridden. :(